# Is there a short circuit 'or' that returns the first 'true' value?

Tags: powershell, short-circuiting

Scheme has a short-circuiting `or` that will return the first non-false value:

```
> (or 10 20 30)
10
> (or #f 20 30)
20
> (or #f)
#f
```

It does not evaluate its arguments until needed.

Is there something like this already in PowerShell?

Here's an approximation of it:

```
function or ()
{
    foreach ($arg in $args) {
        $val = & $arg; if ($val) { $val; break }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> or { 10 } { 20 } { 30 }
10
```

Example:

```
PS C:\> $abc = $null

PS C:\> or { $abc } { 123 }
123

PS C:\> $abc = 456

PS C:\> or { $abc } { 123 }
456
```

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360145/what-is-the-linq-first-equivalent-in-powershell

Answer (score 9):

You could do something like this:

```
10, $false, 20 | ? { $_ -ne $false } | select -First 1
```

The result is either the first value from the input list that isn't `$false`, or `$null`. Since `$null` is among the values that PowerShell [treats as `$false`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx) in comparisons, the above should do what you want.

Comment: This is by FAR the best answer and most useful.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there isn't anything like this built in. I think your function looks pretty good.

It might be more idiomatic to make it take pipelined input:

```
function or
{
    foreach ($x in $input) {
        $val = & $x; if ($val) { $val; break }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
PS > $abc = $null
PS > { $abc },{ 123 } | or
123    
PS > $abc = 456
PS > { $abc },{ 123 } | or
456
```

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to make PowerShell use a Scheme-like syntax by way of your function. Don't do this. Write idiomatic PowerShell. Trying to coerce one language into looking like another language just makes things harder on yourself, introduces **lots** of room for bugs, and will confuse the %$^%&^*( out of whoever has to maintain your code after you're gone.

PowerShell does appear to short-circuit. Put this code in the ISE and set a breakpoint on the `write-output` lines in each function, then start the debugger (F5):

```
function first () {
    write-output "first"
}

function second() {
    write-output "second"
}

$true -or $(first) -or $(second);
$false -or $(first) -or $(second);
$false -or $(second) -or $(first);
```

`$true` evaluates to true (obviously), so it doesn't attempt to process the expression beyond that point. When the next to last line processes, only the breakpoint in `first` processes. When the last line processes, only the breakpoint in `second()` is hit.

Comment: Hello alroc. The `-or` operator does not return the value of the first non-false expression. It always returns either `$true` or `$false`.

Comment: That goes back to your attempting to write PowerShell that pretends to be Scheme instead of writing idiomatic PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you give the function a good name, I think creating such a function is perfectly idiomatic Powershell.  One tweak I would make to OP's implementation is to make passing in a script block optional:

```
function Select-FirstValue {
    $args |
        foreach { if ($_ -is [scriptblock]) { & $_ } else { $_ } } |
        where { $_ } |
        select -First 1
}
```

Then the caller only has to add `{ }` brackets around arguments that could have side-effects or be performance costly.

I'm using such a function as a simple way to provide default values for `param`s from a config file.  It looks something like:

```
function Do-Something {
    param([string]$Arg1)

    $Arg1 = Select-FirstValue $Arg1 { Get-ConfigValue 'arg1' } 'default arg1 val'

    [...]
}
```

This way, the config file only is only attempted to be read if the user does not pass in the argument.